# Graylog getting partial logs

Tags: graylog

I am running graylog server on virtual box with ubuntu OS,
I am connect to gray log server on http://XXX.XXX.186.96:9000/ successfully, can see dashboard, and I am trying to send log from my local running quarkus application to graylog.

`log: debug-enabled-for-tenants: ${TENANT_DEBUG:off} min-level: DEBUG audit-log-enabled: ${AUDIT_LOG_ENABLED:true} console: format: "%d{dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss:SS} %-5p [logType:%X{logType}] [x_request_id:%X{X-Request-ID}] [traceId=%X{traceId}, parentId=%X{parentId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled}], [tenant_id:%X{tenant}] [thread=%t] [class=%c] [operation=%X{operationName}] [error_code=%X{errorCode}] [business_identifiers={%X{businessIdentifiers}}] : %m%n" level: ${LOG_LEVEL:INFO} darken: 0 handler: gelf: enabled: ${GRAYLOG_ENABLED:true} host: ${GRAYLOG_HOST:tcp:xxx.xxx.186.96} port: ${GRAYLOG_PORT:12201} level: ${LOG_LEVEL:TRACE} file:`

and created the input like this

`bind_address: 0.0.0.0 decompress_size_limit: 83886080 max_message_size: 2097152 number_worker_threads: 2 override_source: <empty> port: 12201 recv_buffer_size: 10485760 tcp_keepalive: true tls_cert_file: <empty> tls_client_auth: disabled tls_client_auth_cert_file: <empty> tls_enable: false tls_key_file: <empty> tls_key_password:******** use_null_delimiter: true`

when I am running my application gray log is capturing only the startuplog, thereafter
any other log generated by request to application are logged in console but graylog is failing to capture those

I tried changing the logs levels still it is not working
I am missing something?

[[image]]
[[image]]

[image]

their is one active connection.

Why is the problem caused